# check if a string have repeated letters and subtract the length of the same in factorize calculation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an anagram command for my bot in discord, the thing is when a text is for example "aca" it will show 6 instead of 3.

I don't know if is possible to check if it has a second word in the string in js but here is my code:

```js
const input = cmd;
const output = input
  .split('')
  .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
  .join('');

function factorialize(num) {
  var result = num;
  if (num === 0)
    return 1;
  while (num > 1) {
    num--;
    result *= num;
  }
  return result;
}
```

cmd is just to cut the command like `&command abc` it will return `abc`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve everything your question is asking, you can use the [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function.

To split a string into separate words:

```
<String>.split(/ +/g);
```

To split into characters:

```
<String>.split("");
```

Get length of a string:

```
<String>.length
// or
<String>.split("").length;
```

Full example:

```js
let str = "Hello world";

console.log("Get words in a string:");
console.log(str.split(/ +/g));

console.log("Split into characters:");
console.log(str.split(""));

console.log("Length of string:");
console.log(str.length);

console.log("Length of string without whitespaces:");
console.log(str.split(/ +/g).join("").length);
```